# String to very long sequence of length less than 1 byte

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I can't guess how to solve following problem. Assume I have a string or an array of integer-type variables (uchar, char, integer, whatever). Each of these data type is 1 byte long or more.

I would like to read from such array but read a pieces that are smaller than 1 byte, e.g. 3 bits (values 0-7). I tried to do a loop like

```
cout << ( (tab[index] >> lshift & lmask) | (tab[index+offset] >> rshift & rmask)  );
```

but guessing how to set these variables is out of my reach. What is the metodology to solve such problem?

Sorry if question has been ever asked, but searching gives no answer.

Comment: You want to print the data 3 bits at a time?  That would mean that the bits will span bytes: third piece of data you print will contain information from the first and second bytes.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. I would like like to see my string/array as a very long array of 3-bits sized values and read next 3 bits from it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is not the **best** solution, as there some inefficiencies in the code that could be eliminated, but I think the idea is workable.  I only tested it briefly:

```
void bits(uint8_t * src, int arrayLength, int nBitCount) {
   int idxByte = 0;      // byte index
   int idxBitsShift = 7; // bit index: start at the high bit
   // walk through the array, computing bit sets
   while (idxByte < arrayLength) {
       // compute a single bit set
       int nValue = 0;
       for (int i=2; i>=0; i--) {
        nValue += (src[idxByte] & (1<<idxBitsShift)) >> (idxBitsShift-i);
        if ((--idxBitsShift) < 0) {
            idxBitsShift=8;
            if (++idxByte >= arrayLength) 
                break;
        }
       }
       // print it
       printf("%d ", nValue);
   }

}

int main() {
    uint8_t a[] = {0xFF, 0x80, 0x04};
    bits(a, 3, 3);
}
```

The thing with collecting bits across byte boundaries is a bit of a PITA, so I avoided all that by doing this a bit at a time, and then collecting the bits together in the `nValue`. You could have smarter code that does this three (or however many) bits at a time, but as far as I am concerned, with problems like this it is usually best to start with a simple solution (unless you already know how to do a better one) and then do something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the way the data is arranged in memory strictly depends on :

- the [Endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
- the standard used for computation/representation ( usually it's the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) )
- the type of the given variable

Now, you can't "disassemble" a data structure with this rationale without destroing its own meaning, simply put, if you are going to subdivide your variable in "bitfields" you are just picturing an undefined value.

In computer science there are data structure or informations structured in blocks, like many hashing algorithms/hash results, but a numerical value it's not stored like that and you are supposed to know what you are doing to prevent any data loss.

Another thing to note is that your definition of "pieces that are smaller than 1 byte" doesn't make much sense, it's also highly intrusive, you are losing abstraction here and you can also do something bad.

Comment: Okey, but in base-64 a data is encoded by reading 6 bits and processing it due a substitution table. That is my question: how to  read from an array sequences, where each is < 8 bits ?

Comment: @Adam you are thinking as you should, this is not the right mindset; I know no programming language with a base64 type, nevertheless base64 it's an encoding algorithm so it doesn't even need or depend on a specific type. So you are getting both things wrong. Save yourself time and headaches and use a base64 encoding on a string/char type like so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 without going down to the bits, also if you are using the base64 for any particular reason there is probably a library that can simplify your job.

Comment: pgf: I need to _cut_ an array of ints / uchars into ( in example ) 3 bits lenght pieces or 6 bit pieces ( like in base-64 ), but I do _not_ plan to write another boring base-64 implementation. Base-64 was an example that sometimes data has to be cut to slices smaller than 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best method I could come up with for setting individual bits of a variable:
Assume we need to set the first four bits of variable1 (a char or other byte long variable) to 1010

```
variable1 &= 0b00001111; //Zero the first four bytes
variable1 |= 0b10100000; //Set them to 1010, its important that any unaffected bits be zero
```

This could be extended to whatever bits desired by placing zeros in the first number corresponding to the bits which you wish to set (the first four in the example's case), and placing zeros in the second number corresponding to the bits which you wish to remain neutral in the second number (the last four in the example's case). The second number could also be derived by bit-shifting your desired value by the appropriate number of places (which would have been four in the example's case).

In response to your comment this can be modified as follows to accommodate for increased variability:

For this operation we will need two shifts assuming you wish to be able to modify non-starting and non-ending bits. There are two sets of bits in this case the first (from the left) set of unaffected bits and the second set. If you wish to modify four bits skipping the first bit from the left (1 *these four bits* 111 for a single byte), the first shift would be would be 7 and the second shift would be 5.

```
variable1 &= ( ( 0b11111111 << shift1 ) | 0b11111111 >> shift2 );
```

Next the value we wish to assign needs to be shifted and or'ed in.
However, we will need a third shift to account for how many bits we want to set.
This shift (we'll call it `shift3`) is `shift1` minus the number of bits we wish to modify (as previously mentioned 4).

```
variable1 |= ( value << shift3 );
```

Comment: Thanks :) There're two problems. First: 0bxxx is invalid prefix for ANSI C/C++ value ;) That's no problem. Problem is that masking value + shift length is not constant. I am asking about a principle how to determine these values and how to write such algorithm in a smart way ;)

Comment: @Adam 0b is used by most modern C/C++ compilers as a way to represent binary values. I've edited my answer to include high variability. You can now use this algorithm to edit any amount of bits in the middle of a byte or at the ends. This can be expanded to multiple-byte types (you may have to account for Endianess).